# Calculating cdf given the probability density function

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, density-function

I'm trying to work out the cdf given this probability density function:
$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{4} & {0<x<2}\\
\frac{1}{2}x+c & {2<x<3}\\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}
$$

**While this being the given solution:**
$$
F(x)=\int^x_{-\infty}f(t)dt=\begin{cases}
\int^x_0 \frac{1}{4}dt=\frac{x}{4}\\
\int^x_2(\frac{1}{2}t-\frac{3}{4})dt+k=\frac{x^2-3x}{4}+\frac{1}{2}+k\\
\end{cases}
$$
Under the two levels, F(2) must be the same (reason for introducing k).
$\rightarrow F(2)=\frac{1}{2}=k$
$$
\therefore
F(x)=\begin{cases}
0, & {x<0}\\
\frac{x}{4} & {0 \leqslant x \leqslant 2}\\
\frac{x^2-3x}{4}+1 & {2 \leqslant x \leqslant 3}\\
1, & {x>2}
\end{cases}
$$

**I know how to work out cdfs** but could someone explain to me by demonstration how $\frac{1}{2}x+c$ in the pdf changes to $\frac{x^2-3x}{4}+1$ in the cdf and also why the inequality signs denoting the ranges of x also change respectively.

Comment: The inequality signs don't matter - when talking about a definite integral there is no difference between $<$ and $\leq$ since the "area" under a point in a function is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a probability density function must integrate to $1$. So we have
\begin{align}
1 &= \int_{\mathbb R}f(x)\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \int_0^2 \frac14\ \mathsf dx + \int_2^3\left(\frac12 x+c\right)\ \mathsf dx\\
&= \frac12 + \frac14(3^2-2^2)+c\\
&= \frac74 + c,
\end{align}
so that $c = -\frac34$. To find the distribution function $F(x) = \mathbb P(X\leqslant x)$, we integrate the density; for $0\leqslant x\leqslant 2$ we have
$$
F(x) = \int_0^x f(y)\ \mathsf dy = \int_0^x \frac14\ \mathsf dy = \frac x4. 
$$
For $2\leqslant x\leqslant 3$ we have
\begin{align}
F(x) &= \int_0^x f(y)\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \int_0^2 f(y)\ \mathsf dy + \int_2^x f(x)\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \frac 12 + \int_2^x \left( \frac 12 y-\frac34\right)\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \frac 12 + \frac14(x-2)(x-1)\\
&= \frac{2+(x-1)(x-2)}4\\
&= \frac{x^2-3x}4 + 1.
\end{align}
Note that $F(0)=0$ and $F(3)=1$, as we should expect.